# c++ rounding of numbers away from zero

Tags: c++, double, rounding

Hi i want to round double numbers like this (away from zero) in C++:

```
  4.2 ---->   5
  5.7 ---->   6
 -7.8 ---->  -8
-34.2 ----> -35
```

What is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: From the (original) title "C++ Double rounding", I thought you meant rounding a number twice, just to be sure :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
inline double myround(double x)
{
  return x < 0 ? floor(x) : ceil(x);
}
```

As mentioned in [the article Huppie cites](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3638/), this is best expressed as a template that works across all float types

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor

or, thanks to Pax, a non-function version:

```
x = (x < 0) ? floor(x) : ceil(x);
```

Comment: Good call, @Ruben, added a non-function variant and gave you a vote. Hope you don't mind (the edit, that is, obviously you don't mind the vote).

Comment: Waiting for 3k myself - added in an inline specifier  - I'd tend to try to find a good name and stick it in a util lib, probably as a template for all floats -- it wouldnt cost any efficiency and allows you to quickly isolate or change all usages of it

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice article about a similar problem on [CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3638/). The easy solution to your problem should be something like this:

```
double customRound( double value ) const {
   return value < 0 ? floor( value ) : ceil( value );
}
```

A better solution is the one mentioned in the article, which uses a template:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// symmetric round up
// Bias: away from zero
template <typename FloatType>
FloatType ceil0( const FloatType& value )
{
   FloatType result = std::ceil( std::fabs( value ) );
   return (value < 0.0) ? -result : result;
}
```

Comment: Why isnt it called customFloor - it's neither :P

Comment: I see in the cited article its impl'd as <code>
template <typename FloatType>
  FloatType ceil0( const FloatType& value )
    {
    FloatType result = std::ceil( std::fabs( value ) );
    return (value < 0.0) ? -result : result;
    }
</code>

Interesting article, +1

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink: 'Round' should be better :)... btw... you have some ninja typing skills ;-)

Comment: Typing or cut and pasting :P My typing is actually quite embarassing - see http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/TypersharkNdashImproveYouTypingInJustMinutesADay.aspx (No, havent done it yet).  I think even 'Round' is a bit generic and has a generally understood meaning in the stdlib - point is its a very specific algorithm he wants, and using either floor, ceil or round doesnt accurately convey that.

Comment: since you're branching anyway, the absolute value is somewhat redundant: `return (value < 0.0) ? -std::ceil(-value) : std::ceil(value)`

Answer (score 2):

The `x < 0 ? floor(x) : ceil(x);` approach of [Ruben Bartelink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1326524/2410359) is good.  Yet consider what happens with special cases of `x = -0.0`, `x = NaN`.

Rather than have `myround(-0.0)` potentially return `+0.0`<sup>1</sup> and have `myround(NaN)` return with a changed payload of the `NaN`, consider the below.

`myround_alt(-0.0)` returns `-0.0`.

`myround_alt(NaN)` *more likely* returns an unchanged payload NaN.  Not-a-number stuff is tricky and not well defined.  IAC, it is the `myround_alt(-0.0)` --> `-0.0` I am seeking.

```
inline double myround_alt(double x) {
  if (x > 0) return ceil(x);
  if (x < 0) return floor(x);
  return x;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>[IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) specifies `ceil(±0)` returns `±0` so this approach not needed with implementations that strictly follow that spec.  Yet many C floating point implementation do not follow that (C does not require it) or fail in such comer cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 double rounded = _copysign(ceil(abs(x)), x);
```

Comment: but ceil returns bigger integer value if my value is -3.4 and i add 0.5 it will be -2.9 and ceil will return -2 i want something to make -4

Comment: ceil(x + 0.5) for x=5.7 would yield 7 instead of 6, wouldn't it?

Comment: It still doesnt work for the negative ones as specced, see the samples at the place I linked

Comment: Now it's not as efficient anymore, even if it uses an interesting trick - where is _copysign from?

Comment: This is a good technique: a smart compiler/runtime should allow `abs` to bit-AND the sign bit with 0, do the ceil (pray that this is done fast), then re-sign the result by bit-ORing its sign bit with the original's. *No conditionals* = no branch mis-predictions = no pipeline flushes = very fast.

Comment: Why is this voted down? The answer given here was wrong before, but after correction, this is now a good answer. As @Ahmed Fasih pointed out, this solution only requires some bit-AND and bit-OR operation, so it should be fast with low latency.