# Is there an "inverted" trunc function in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, math, rounding

Is there a function in C or C ++ - similar to trunc - that rounds off negative numbers and rounds up positive numbers?
Like in this example:

-3.3 to -4 or 2.1 to 3

I could only find the "inverse" function trunc. But can hardly believe that this does not exist. Do I really have to first query the positivity via if and then round it up accordingly? I need this because I have the sign of the scalar product between two vectors. So either 1, -1 or 0.

Comment: using floor on negative numbers?

Comment: *" I need this because I have the sign of the scalar product between two vectors. So either 1, -1 or 0."* Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Duplicate of [c++ rounding of numbers away from zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326510/c-rounding-of-numbers-away-from-zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can use an inline conditional to either return the `floor` or the `ceil`. Here:

```
#include <math.h>
inline double InvertedTrunc(double Number) {
    return Number < 0 ? floor(Number) : ceil(Number);
}
```

Another approach to achieve this functionality is just truncating the number, and increasing its absolute value by one. This will also work. Does not require `math.h` However, it is not recommended for large numbers because of overflow:

```
inline double InvertedTrunc(double Number) {
    return (Number == (int)Number ? Number : ((int)Number)+(Number < 0 ? -1 : 1)); //casting to int truncates it
} //However, this option is susceptible to overflow, and it is not recommended for large numbers
```

Comment: OP seeks a function "similar to `trunc`": `trunc` returns a `double`.

Comment: @exnihilo Why? `double` _stores_ the decimal points but the trunc is basically removing it.

Comment: @Holt Ok fine... But what about a long int or a long long int?

Comment: @Asadefa I'm curious how a larger integer type would address the problems pointed out by Holt. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok. He is afraid that a plain `int` is not even big enough to hold the integral portion of a possible double passed in. So increasing the size of the int might solve the problem.

Comment: @Asadefa You still have the `inf` issue or any other floating-point specific value that are well-handled by `floor`/`ceil` but not by a `int` conversion. BTW, your second version is incorrect for values that are already integers.

Comment: @Asadefa You'd need about a 1024 bit integer to store the largest values of a `double`. I don't know of any platform that offers anything larger than 128. So using a larger integer only delays the problem slightly. And it does not address the other concern of handling non-numeric values.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If you need a 1024 bit integer to store the largest values of a double, then how does a double store the largest values of itself with less than 1024

Comment: @Asadefa Because it only stores a few significant digits along with an exponent. Basically by using scientific notation. Integers can't do that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But then it is less precise

Comment: @Asadefa Yes `double` loses precision as it's value gets large or small.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok now I understand

Comment: If you assume that `double` cannot represent numbers outside the range [`INTMAX_MIN`, `INTMAX_MAX`] precisely, you could leave `double` values that fall outside that range unchanged, otherwise do the integer truncation trick with `intmax_t` values.